# AVPlayer handling buffer when the app is in background state

Tags: iphone, background, buffer, avplayer

I have asked this question in Apple Developer forum earlier today but there is no response. But anyway, I would like to ask again in here.

I am making an audio live streaming app. The problem I faced with is that the audio streaming cannot be resumed to play when it is paused due to buffer empty in background mode.

I am using Reachability to check network reachability, and AVPlayer for audio streaming. In debug mode, when the app passed some breakpoints, the execution becomes frozen. When the network state changes, Reachability does not have any responds.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I am also make an App of live audio streaming.bot I am use MPMovieViewController for play audio and its work perfect for me for streaming live audio nd it also play after resume...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [mattgallagher/AudioStreamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) link as its best `library` for `audio streaming`

Refer [background handling of audio streamer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402652/1106035) link.